# Adding HTML to iframe is not working properly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I tried to add html content to my iframe but it is not working and I can't see why is this happening, this is my HTML code I try to add

```
let cadena_html = `<table align="center" class="tabla" style="margin-top: 10px;" style="height: auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr style="font-size: 10px;">
                    <th width="30">Cant.</th>
                    <th width="80">Descripci&oacute;n</th>
                    <th width="30">Prec.</th>
                    <th width="30">Desc.</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">-----------------------------------------------------</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">1</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">Sobre de plastico</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">$ 2</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">$ 0.00</td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">1</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">Prueba de etiquetas</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">$ 10</td>
                    <td style="font-size: 9px;">$ 0.00</td>
                 </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">-----------------------------------------------------</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">Descuento: $</span></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">0.00</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">TOTAL: $</span></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">12.00</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">Recibido: $</span></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">0.00</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">Cambio: $</span></td>
                    <td align="right"><span style="font-size: 10px;">0.00</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`;
```

And I'm trying it in this way

```
$('#ticket_venta').contents().find('body').html(cadena_html);
```

I'm using template literals `` and console is not showing me the error, if I add another simple html it works like `<h1>Example</h1>`, I tried to change my double quotes by single quotes but still nothing.

You can check an example code here

https://jsfiddle.net/jjtqqmmb/

I hope you can help me to figure out what is the issue, thank you.

Comment: Works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/jjtqqmmb/1/

Comment: The fiddle in your question isn't using string template literals.

Comment: ... and the fiddle in your question tries to find `html` instead of `body`

Comment: You're creating invalid HTML, `table` is not permitted content of [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html).

Comment: @zero298 yes, I did notice it, I fixed but still nothing

Comment: @adeneo Yes I see, I'm checking my code against it to see why I did bad or something Im missing